# Unable to accept user input in bash

Tags: bash

```
while
   echo "Do you want to continue y/n?"
   read install_to_default
   [[ -z $install_to_default || $install_to_default != [yYnN] ]]
do echo "The response is invalid. A valid response is y or n."; done
```

Running the above script as root causes no problems, but when I try to run the script as a different user with the below changes it causes an infinite loop.

```
sudo -u piggy -i <<'EOF'
while
    echo "Do you want to continue y/n?"
    read install_to_default
    [[ -z $install_to_default || $install_to_default != [yYnN] ]]
    do echo "The response is invalid. A valid response is y or n."; done
EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stdin of the `sudo` process has been redirected to the here-document
`<<` and the `read` command in the loop doesn't wait for the user's
input on console. Please try to change the `read` line to:

```
read -u 1 install_to_default
```

Technically it may not be the best idea to use descriptor 1 for
the purpose. Strictly we should use other descriptor such as 3 with
the `-C 4` option to the `sudo` command. But this solution will require
to change the `sudoers policy` which may rather cause more problems.

Comment: the bash script will be executed as root, so will it still need a policy change?

Comment: As for the root privilege, you do not have to change the policy as long as the specified user belongs to the sudoers group.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read user input this way because the input stream is already captured by the here-document script.

If you want to read user input from the terminal, while using a here-document as the `sudo` script, then read from `/dev/tty`

```sh
sudo -u piggy -i <<'EOF'
while
    printf %s\\n "Do you want to continue y/n?"
    read -r install_to_default </dev/tty
    [ -z "$install_to_default" ] || [ -n "${install_to_default%[yYnN]}" ]
    do
      printf %s\\n "The response is invalid. A valid response is y or n."
    done
EOF
```